# Query problem not working

Tags: php, mysql

Today i'm getting this error with define categories.

*The categories are defined like this:*

```
 $categorie=$_GET['categorie'];    
 if($categorie==nimic)    
 $cat="nimic";    
 elseif($categorie==Aventura)    
 $cat="Aventura";    
 elseif($categorie==Dragoste)    
 $cat="Dragoste";    
 elseif($categorie==Politiste)    
 $cat="Politiste";    
 elseif($categorie==Pentru-Copii)    
 $cat="Pentru-Copii";    
 elseif($categorie==Romanesti)    
 $cat="Romanesti";    
 elseif($categorie==Mistere)    
 $cat="Mistere";    
 elseif($categorie==Scient-Fiction)    
 $cat="Scient-Fiction";    
 elseif($categorie==Vampiri)    
 $cat="Vampiri";    
 elseif($categorie==Thriller)    
 $cat="Thriller";    
 elseif($categorie==Drama)    
 $cat="Drama";    
 elseif($categorie==Erotic)    
 $cat="Erotic";    
 elseif($categorie==Mitologie)    
 $cat="Mitologie";
```

The query is:

```
 $query="SELECT *    
 FROM carte    
 WHERE categorie='$cat'    
 AND uploader='$username'    
 ORDER BY data_ad    
 DESC LIMIT $lista";
```

Well the problem is that at the first 4 `$cat` is working, is displaying the results that can be edited. But at the rest of the `$cat` is resulting 0 files to be edited..

In phpmyadmin i've tried manually to check the query by replacing `$cat` with the category who is not working and the `$username` with an valid username filled under the row uploader.

Manually it is working. So where should be the problem? any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I'm really, really uncomfortable with the way you're not using quotes.  I would recommend this instead:

```
$categorie=$_GET['categorie'];
if($categorie=='nimic')
$cat="nimic";
elseif($categorie=='Aventura')
$cat="Aventura";
elseif($categorie=='Dragoste')
$cat="Dragoste";
elseif($categorie=='Politiste')
$cat="Politiste";
elseif($categorie=='Pentru-Copii')
$cat="Pentru-Copii";
...
```

Notice the metacharacter ("-") in the last category.  Just sayin'... ;)

Comment: In db under categorie, i have putted 2 categories splited with "-"    the query is working at "Pentru-Copii" but after that category is displaying me 0 results on the next categories

Comment: @Darius - why not take Paul's advice and use quotes around your strings and see if this fixes your problem?

Answer (score 2):

First of all it seems like whatever `$categorie` is, `$cat` is, so why is that code needed ?

Second, strings should ALWAYS be denoted by using quotes (' or ")

something like this should cover it:

```
if (isset($_GET['categorie']) && is_string($_GET['categorie'])) {
    $cat = $_GET['categorie'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use hyphens in the constants (I do hope they're constants). It's interpreted as substraction, that is, `Pentru-Copii` is the value of `Pentru` minus the value of `Copii`.

I assume the categories coming from the `$_GET['categorie']` are numerical. It'd be better to create an array and use that to find the values:

```
$categories = array(
    264 => 'Aventura',
    621 => 'Dragoste',
    ...
);

$cat = $categories[ $_GET['categorie'] ];
```

Or if the category is always a string you can just do `$cat = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET[ 'categorie' ] )`.

Comment: absolutely correct.  That's what I tried to say in my post.  Two issues: a) the "dash == subtract" problem (by not quoting the literal), and b) why the complicated if/else block (or $categories[] array) if "_$GET['categorie']" always == $cat?

Answer (score 1):

> any ideea

ever tried to print out your resulting query and run it in the phpmyadmin? and compare it with one you made in phpmyadmin?

also there is no point in such a list of elseif's.
a single line

```
$cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['categorie']);
```

is enough

Answer (score 1):

Emm .. are those constants there ?

Shouldnt you instead of that if-elseif fest do something like :

```
$category=$_GET['categorie'];
$data = array( 
    1 => 'nimic', 
    2 => 'Aventura',
    3 => 'Dragoste',
    4 => 'Politiste',
        etc ...
);

if ( !array_key_exists( $category , $data )  )
{
   $category = 1 // set default category
}

$cat = $data[ $category ];
```

And .. please , learn to use [PDO](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) prepared statements:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo', 'login', 'password');
$sth = $db->prepare('
   SELECT * FROM carte
   WHERE categorie=:category AND uploader=:user
   ORDER BY data_ad DESC LIMIT :limit'
);
$sth->bindParam(':category', $cat, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':user', $username , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: what's the point in having a copy of database contents in the code?

Comment: of the whole catalog. all these Politiste and nimic are already in the database. what's the point in typing it in the code?

Comment: @col-shrapnel and where in his topic did you read that ? The categories would be in a separated table, **if** they even are in DB. **And** i am assuming that the IF-ELSE block check based on constants.

Comment: @col-shrapnel  `if($categorie==nimic)` compares `$categorie` with constant `nimic` (if it is defined) .. and i assume that it is there for a reason

Comment: ...and if it's not defined - it compares `categorie` with *string* `nimic` and i assume that it is there just because the OP is weak  with syntax  :)

Answer (score 0):

Edited.

FIrst you prepare an array from MySQL query, then search the array with a php function:

```
$categorie=$_GET['categorie'];

if(in_array($allowedCategories, $categorie)){
  $cat = $categorie;
}
```

That's all.

Comment: it's not the cleanest way. there is no point in making a manual copy of database contents.

Comment: Oops. Didn't see the Query. Early morning, huh :)